# Experiment on specific version of Android with Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to serve an experiment (via Google Tag Manager) to only a specific SDK level and above users of my Android app?

For e.g. only Lollipop and greater devices should be part of the experiment and in that subset only 50% of users should see a change and the other 50% should not?

I have a pretty basic knowledge of GTM and have used it to set variables to control visbility of buttons etc. but am not too familiar with how to check for SDK version in GTM when sending a value to users? Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GTM you can activate Built-In variables, one of those are OS version and SDK version as you can see on screenshot below (SDK version is at the bottom of the list):
[image]

You can use them to create your trigger for specific OS version & SDK version as you want:

[image]

As for 50/50 testing, there is no built-in functionality in GTM as far as I know. If you can only use GTM interface maybe you can do a workaround and use GTM's random number Variable to use as 50/50 chance trigger?

[Disclaimer: I have never done this before, but I would try this. It will not give you exact 50/50 split] If you go to Vairiables -> User-Defined Variables -> New -> Choose variable type   you should see Random Number under "Utilities". If you save it as custom variable you should be able to use in your trigger for example:

[image]

(the number is half of the Random number limit)